# YA dystopian set in flooded London, protagonist is a girl

Tags: story-identification

I read a sample of this book on Kindle...

Starts off with the protaganist (a girl) saying how she lied to her mom about being sick and stayed at home that day.

The reason she did so was to avoid a boy classmate who was always bullying her, due to the way she looks (if I remember correctly).

She lives with her mom as her dad is gone (dead? left? run away? cannot remember...)

They live in a 2-bed flat that is split over 2 floors. She always sleeps in the same room with her mom as the other bedroom door was always shut and she wasn't allowed to even go into that room without her mom's permission.

The day it (big storms) happened her mom went out to work and never came back. She was alone all by herself for a few days, and it happens she was very ill so by the time she was well enough to get up it was already few days after the storms had happened.

She didn't realise there was a big storm until she stood up and looked outside her windows and saw everywhere flooded.

Her mom never came home.

It was set in London. This I know because just before the storms started, she went to a local supermarket and the store owner told her she should leave London and go far away to the north which was what he intended to do.

Oh, she did go into that other bedroom and saw that the windows were shattered and a bird (crow? pigeon? dove? cannot remember...) had done the damage and lie bleeding and dying in the room.

I can't remember the name of this book... has anyone read it?

Comment: Isn't there a way to check what you have been downloading to your kindle?

Comment: @Deion:
Looks like there are some people finding solutions to that in http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle%20active%20content?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx3NHHKKZWSWCBP&cdThread=Tx2E65PJ7SY03Z

Comment: @Deion and SeanDuggan yes I looked through my Kindle list but couldn't find it, moreover I changed to a new phone recently and found it didn't store all the samples I've downloaded on my old phone!

Comment: @SeanDuggan I tried one of the solutions on that link and went to Kindle on my computer but it didn't list any of the free samples. Guess those samples were device-specific? :(

Comment: Very very long shot: "This Is Not Your City"

Comment: @barrycarter just googled "This Is Not Your City" which is a collection of short stories, but unfortunately it isn't this one...

Comment: There are similarities with a section of "Flood" by Stephen Baxter, but the similar scene is not the opening. The rest of the book is very different, but if you only read a section it might be a match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Paradigm (book 1 of a series)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KXFDDDI) by Ceri A. Lowe seems to be what you're looking for. I opened up the free sample and the first chapter does mirror your description (there's a prologue told in a different character's point of view).

Amazon's summary:

> What if the end of the world was just the beginning?
>
> Alice Davenport awakens from a fever to find her mother gone and the
>   city she lives in ravaged by storms – with few survivors.
>
> When Alice is finally rescued, she is taken to a huge underground
>   bunker owned by the mysterious Paradigm Industries. As the storms
>   worsen, the hatches close.
>
> 87 years later, amidst the ruins of London, the survivors of the
>   Storms have reinvented society. The Model maintains a perfect balance
>   – with inhabitants routinely frozen until they are needed by the
>   Industry.
>
> Fifteen-year-old Carter Warren knows his time has come. Awoken from
>   the catacombs as a contender for the role of Controller General, it is
>   his destiny to succeed – where his parents failed.
>
> But Carter soon discovers that the world has changed, in ways that
>   make him begin to question everything that he believes in. As Carter
>   is forced to fight for those he loves and even for his life, it seems
>   that the key to the future lies in the secrets of the past...
>
> Set in a post-apocalyptic London and told from both Alice and Carter’s
>   point of view, Paradigm is a dark, intelligent and compelling read. An
>   exciting new dystopian series not to be missed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes this is it! I read a sample of this and so glad you found it for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about *[Raider's Ransom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6325690-raiders-ransom)*, also called *Flood Child*, by Emily Diamond.

> It's the 22nd century and, because of climate change, much of England is underwater. Poor Lilly is out fishing with her trusty sea-cat when greedy raiders pillage the town--and kidnap the prime minister's daughter. Her village blamed, Lilly decides to find the girl. Off she sails, in secret. And with a ransom: a mysterious talking jewel. "If I save his daughter," Lilly reasons, "the prime minister's sure to reward me." Little does Lilly know that it will take more than grit to outwit the tricky, treacherous piratical tribes!

Comment: What makes you think this is the book? Can you add any details about how it fits the OP's criteria?